# Apache OpenNLP Persist Model to DB

Tags: mongodb, java-8, couchbase, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am exploring Apache OpenNLP product in my project and one of the requirement is to persist the trained model in DB - Mongo DB / couchbase in my case.
Right now primarily I am looking to store document categorizer model output to DB so that I do not have to rerun unless its modified

I see that the library classes are not serializable e.g. DocumentCategorizerME and I am getting json deserilization exception if I try to retrieve the persisted records so want to know if someone is already doing that.

In general what would be the approach to persist even if I want to use any other open source NLP products.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach that can be followed is using DoccatModel.serialize to serialize and store the model to Mongo DB - GridFs

Couchbase DB has hard limit of 20 MB size for binary data to be stored.